# Edit JSON Response in AngularJS and bind to the list

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I know how to read form json and bind the output to the view however I would like to add some logic into the output and bid converted data. How do I output my forEach to the array and than do ng-repeat based on it or combine my ajax data binding with my amendments?

At the moment if I change

$scope.fleet = newData; => $scope.fleet = data;

and view.html eg. {{item.name}} everything works but I would like to add some changes to the name before binding.

My code:

controler.js

```
function LoadFleetControler($scope){
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://someapi/list',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {

  var newData = [];

  angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){

  /* ############################ Options ############################ */

  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var thisDate = d.getDate() + '/' + padLeft(month,2)  + '/' + d.getFullYear();
  var thisCycle = dateToDays(thisDate, value.end_bill_date) + 1; // Include last 24H


   /* ############################ Scope ############################ */


   $scope.fleetUser = value.name;
   $scope.fleetCycle = 'Cycle: ' + thisCycle + ' days left (' + value.end_bill_date + ')';
   $scope.fleetPercentageUsed = value.percentage_used;
   $scope.fleetCycleColor = highlighSwitch(value.percentage_used);

}, newData);

console.log(newData);

$scope.fleet = newData;
$scope.$apply();

},
error: function(data) {

$scope.error = true;
$scope.$apply();

}
});  

}
```

view.html

```
<div ng-controller="LoadFleetControler">
<ons-list>
<ons-list-item ng-show="error">Server Connection Error</ons-list-item>
<ons-list-item class="topcoat-list__item__line-height" ng-repeat="item in fleet">
{{fleetUser}}
<small>{{fleetCycle}}</small>
</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `angular.forEach()`, you are assigning items to the scope, when you probably meant to create new objects and add them to the `newData` array...

```
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){

        // ...

        var newItem = {};
        newItem.fleetUser = value.name;
        newItem.fleetCycle = 'Cycle: ' + thisCycle + ' days left (' + value.end_bill_date + ')';
        newItem.fleetPercentageUsed = value.percentage_used;
        newItem.fleetCycleColor = highlighSwitch(value.percentage_used);

        newData.push(newItem);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi with your example I'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'push'

Comment: Do you still have `var newData = [];` before `angular.forEach`?

Comment: Yeah the issue was with this.push(newItem) got it working with newData.push(newItem); Thanks

Comment: One more think how do I add HTML into angular variable? eg. newItem.fleetCycleColor = '<p>' + value.percentage_used + '</p>'; $scope always outputs HTML as text not HTML?

Comment: Weird... if `newData` exists and it is passed as the context into `angular.forEach()`, `this` should be `newData`... Anyhow, I'll update the answer. Thanks.